# How to pass an object without losing its reference?

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen, wasm-pack

I am creating a library in Rust and using it in JavaScript, using wasm-pack to build the output

#### Rust

```rust
extern crate wasm_bindgen;

use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Foo {
    i: i32,
    j: i32,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Foo {
    pub fn create(n: i32) {
        Foo { i: n, j: n }
    }
}
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Bar {
    foos: Vec<Foo>,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Bar {
    pub fn create() -> Bar {
        Bar { foos: Vec::new() }
    }
    pub fn add(&mut self, bar: Bar) {
        self.foos.push(bar);
    }
}
```

#### JavaScript

```js
import init from 'm.js';
import {Foor, Bar} from 'm.js';


async run() {
   await init();
   let f= Foo::create();
   let b= Bar::create();
   console.log(f); // it has Pointer here
   b.add(f);
   console.log(f); // it loses the pointer due to the de-referencing
}

run();
```

Since I used the `Bar` type, as soon as I call the method I lose the pointer that I have in the JavaScript context. How can I save the reference of `foo` and not lose the pointer to it?

Comment: You can't. Once you've moved the value, your variable no longer has ownership of it. In addition, the address of the value is no longer valid. If you could do what you wanted, you'd introduce memory unsafety. I'd highly recommend thoroughly reading [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) to gain a better understanding of Rust before complicating it by interacting with multiple languages.